# How to make a scatterplot in seaborn from 2 numerical columns and 1 categorical column?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, scatter-plot

[image: pic of my dataframe]

I want to make a scatterplot in seaborn (but I'm open to other ways to execute this) from two numerical columns of data and one categorical column of data, with the two titles of the numerical columns on the x axis, the values of the numerical columns on the y axis, and the cat column represented by hue.
[this is kind of like what I want, with the names, firstgame and lastgame on the x axis instead of 1 minute and 15 minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGfZo.png)

There are 50 basketball teams in my dataset, each with their own row (so there are 50 rows). Each team has a label, "good" or "bad". The label is the categorical column that I want in my plot. The first numerical column I want has the number of attendees for the first game of the season and the second numerical column has the number of attendees for the last game of the season. I figured I could plot this using seaborn, but I'm not sure how to designate x and y. I tried add the two num columns together in a list and then going from there but that didn't really work out. Any suggestions...? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: instead of describing your data, please provide a sample.

Comment: if df is your DataFrame, 
`sns.scatterplot(x="firstgame", y="lastgame", hue="label", data=df)`

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[8.98, 1.56, 'fail'],
        [8.91, 5.22, 'success'],
        [5.39, 2.13, 'fail'],
        [5.06, 1.61, 'fail'],
        [5.84, 2.86, 'fail']] 

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['firstgame','lastgame','label'])

ax=sns.scatterplot(x='firstgame',y='lastgame',hue='label',data=df)
plt.show()
```

This will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
## sample data, ignore this 
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, (50,2)),
                  columns=['firstgame','lastgame'])
df['label'] = np.random.choice(['good','bad'], 50)

## replace 'index' with your index name if any
sns.lineplot(data=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index','label']), 
             hue='label', 
             style='variable', 
             x='index',
             y='value')
```

Output:

[image]